# How to fetch random order from One-to-Many relationships in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, random, fetch, laravel-10

I have a One-to-Many relationship

- The "Question" table has many Options,
- The "Options" table belongtsTo "Question" table.

I’am trying to fetch, in the same time, random order for my question and random order for options.

I’ am getting the Questions in random order, ***but I don’t know how to get a random order for the options as well***.

Here below you have my code :

**My controller:**

```
    public function showQ(){
        return view('my_view',[
            
            'Questions' => Question::inRandomOrder()->with('Option')->get(),
            
        ]);
```

**In the view**

```
    @foreach($Questions as $question)
      
       {{$question -> DbQuestions}}

       @foreach($Questions -> Option as $option)
           
          {{$option -> DbOptions}}
       
       @endforeach

    @endforeach
```

**Question model**

```
  public function Option(): HasMany {
        return $this -> hasMany(Option::class);
    }
```

**Option model**

```
  public function Question(): BelongsTo {
        return $this-> belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
```

Is there any one to clarify the issues?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

> (***Best Practise 1***)  *singular/plural* and always *write relationship in a small case*. `options` not `Option` or `Options`.

> (***Best Practise 2***) Use m*eaningful function names* `showQ` would be nice if you use `show`. (Standard *Resource controller methods*)

---

You can move `inRandomOrder()` into sub function like this

```
public function showQ(){
    return view('my_view',[
        'Questions' => Question::inRandomOrder()
            ->with(['Option' => function ($query) {
                $query->inRandomOrder();
            }])
            ->get(),
    ]);
}
```

**In View**

```
@foreach($Questions as $question)
   {{$question->DbQuestions}}

   @foreach($question->options as $option)           
      {{$option->DbOptions}}       
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**In `Question` Model**

```
public function options(): HasMany {
    return $this -> hasMany(Option::class);
}
```

**In `Option` Model**

```
public function question(): BelongsTo {
    return $this-> belongsTo(Question::class);
}
```